# Multiple LinearGradientBrushes WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, gradient

I have a list of colors and corresponding timestamps, for example:

```
00 seconds - #ff0000
30 seconds - #00ff00
60 seconds - #0000ff
```

And I want to create an indicator bar on my GUI which shows the colors getting interpolated over time. The bar should look something like this:

![Example of a bar][1]

I tried it this way:

```
<Rectangle Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1" GradientStops="{Binding Instance.GradientStops}">

                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
```

Code-Behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<GradientStop> GradientStops {
        get {
            ObservableCollection<GradientStop> stops = new ObservableCollection<GradientStop>();
            double totalLength = this.sections[this.sections.Count - 1].SecondsSinceStart;
            foreach(var section in this.sections)
            {
                double percentage = section.SecondsSinceStart / totalLength;
                var newStop = new GradientStop(section.Color, percentage);
                stops.Add(newStop);
            }
            return stops;
        }
    }
```

But I see no gradient what so ever. I went into the debugger and the values are just as expected.

Comment: I think you want to [animate an object using key frames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-an-object-by-using-key-frames). The example there is actually a series of linear gradient brushes changing over time, so you're in luck.

Comment: No its not an animation the values of the timestamps etc are coming from numericupdowns and its not supposed to animate. the more realistic approch would be to have a kind of button which refreshes this bar, but even then I would like to do this via bindings to have the ui separated from the logic.

Comment: Bind the Offset of a GradientStop to the TimeStamp and add a ValueConverter to this binding that turns the TimeStamp into a value between 0 and 1

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, I'll try it

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I tried it with the code in the opening post, but it does not show up, you know why?

Comment: Turns out that there is a GradientStopCollection. Simply using a IEnumerable<T> would have been a tad bit too intuitive, thanks microsoft...

Comment: I suggest you write answer for your Q

Comment: Oh, right - I forgot

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

The Binding expects a GradientStopCollection not a List.